# remove specific object does not work in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of object containing a reference to their parent object.

I am trying to remove every objects within a specific parent (so equals to the parent object).

If I do:

```
System.out.println(parent);
```

my console output:

```
ParentObject@1f8166e5
```

if I do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
   if(array.get(i).getParent().equals(parent)){
      array.remove(i);
   }
}
```

And (test)

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
   if(array.get(i).getParent().equals(parent)){
      System.out.println(parent + ":" + array.get(i).getParent());

   }
}
```

My console output something like:

```
ParentObject@1f8166e5:ParentObject@1f8166e5
```

What's wrong with the snippet above?
Why `array.remove(i)` did not work?

Comment: What is the indication that `remove()` doesn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that after you've removed element `i` (which moves everything after it up the list - the element at index `n + 1` now has index `n` etc) you're then *skipping* the next element. So if you have two consecutive elements to remove, you're missing the second one. The simplest fix is to work from the *end*:

```
for (int i = array.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   if (array.get(i).getParent().equals(parent)) {
      array.remove(i);
   }
}
```

EDIT: As noted in another answer, it's generally better to use an iterator for removal anyway. In your case, this would look like this:

```
// We don't know what the Foo type is...
for (Iterator<Foo> iterator = array.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Foo element = iterator.next();
    if (element.getParent().equals(parent)) {
        iterator.remove(); // Note: *not* array.remove(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard: Not shuffle in terms of "randomly reassign" but shuffle as in "everything else moves up one place" - if you had an element A with index 10, and you remove the element at index 2, element A now has index 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove objects while iterating. You should use `Iterator` if you want to remove element while iterating

Comment: He is not using an `Iterator` but an indexed for loop. Removing works, it is just not a good pattern and may lead to problems as @Jon Skeet hinted.

Comment: I've added an Iterator-based approach to my answer.